# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version is slow

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015, intel

Here are the technical details about my  DELL Inspiron 15 3000 Series
 computer:

- -Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
- -Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00081
- -Windows 8.1
- -Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
- -RAM: 4.00GB
- -64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

The computer is a new DELL Inspiron 15 3000 Series.
The problem is that starting Visual Studio is very Slow, and running Visual Studio applications in debug mode takes a long time.

**Update:**

Also, Look at Microsoft's Recommended System Requirements for Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, it seems my system should meet the necessary requirements.  Why is it so slow?

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#1

Visual Studio Community 2015

For additional information on Operating System support, see the Visual Studio 2015 Compatibility page.

Hardware requirements
•1.6 GHz or faster processor
•1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
•4 GB of available hard disk space
•5400 RPM hard drive
•DirectX 9-capable video card running at 1024 x 768 or higher display resolution

System requirements

•On Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, update 2919355 (also available through Windows Update) is required for Visual Studio 2015 to install successfully.

Additional requirements
•For Windows Store and Windows Universal app development ◦Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 and development require Windows 8.1 Update or later.
◦Windows Phone 8.0 development require Windows 8.1 Update (x64) or later.
◦For emulator support (Windows or Android), Windows 8.1 (x64) Professional edition or higher or Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise (x64) editions are required. In addition, you need a processor that supports Client Hyper-V and Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).

Could someone please suggest some ways of making Visual Studio run faster?

Comment: That's not a lot of RAM or processing power for Windows 8.1, let alone VS 2015. Honestly, you need a better machine.

Comment: Ok, but did you see my update about Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 System Requirements?

Comment: Please look up the definition of "minimum"

Comment: @user1338998 As Lance pointed out, these are the minimum requirements, which just means your computer can run the software. You're pretty close to some of those minima, though, so it's no surprise that your machine can barely handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Intel U CPU is optimized for battery life and not power. Also the 4GB are the absolute minimum for Windows 8.1 + development tools like Visual Studio. So your device is consumer device but not really fast enough for a business development machine.

Comment: May I please know how you determined if my Intel U CPU is optimized for battery life, therefore, Not power?  I thought that had optimization based on battery life or power was configured in our settings.

Comment: the complete U cpus are optimized for low power consumption to improve battery life.

Comment: alot of assuptions made in this answer

Comment: @Mike no, that are facts. The  i3-4005U is a CPU which you should not use for developer systems, it is designed for Ultrabooks/Tablets. It is 66% slower compared to my 3230m: http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i3-4005U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-3230M/m7028vs2772 and here my CPU is sometimes busy during VS tasks (compilation of large projects)

Comment: Yes but I have an 8 core machine with 16 gig and my machine also runs slowly occasionally

Comment: @Mike analyze the cpu usage with WPR/WPA/Perfview to see why it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on magicandre191's answer,

The 'recommended' specs usually only account for a bare minimum to run Visual Studio with all enhancements, gui designers, etc turned off.  Visual Studio can be used in a minimal mode (equivalent of a glorified Notepad) by turning off all the enhanced features (like XAML designer, optimize experience, hardware acceleration, code insights, debugging, etc).

The issue is further compounded by adding in use of bleeding edge frameworks (4.6) which while they contain optimizations, also require more CPU / memory.  Visual Studio is mainly a CPU hog.

While it is true that energy saving processors are powerful, comparing with processors that require more power ( same quarter of the year release as their energy saving counter-parts ), tend to give more in return.

An example of something older, but works fairly well (XAML/WPF ui designer is still slow), is as follows :

- AMD FX-4100
- 16GB DDR3 PC10700 AMD Brand
- 256GB SSD
- GeForce GTX 650 Ti
- Windows 10 Pro (lots of stuff disabled)
- No AntiVirus or Antimalware etc (aside from what comes with windows)

Even with these specs, performance with all the visual stuff enabled, can be rather laggy.

If you must code on the machine with the above specs, you might want to try out Microsoft's slim code editor [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) for your project needs.